# Is there a better way to save data to a column with logic calculated in a model using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a 'work_space' model that has_many 'reviews'. In my 'reviews' model, users are able to rate a work_space with an integer stored in a `:rating` column. I created a method in my WorkSpace model to calculate the average of all reviews for a particular work_space.

class WorkSpace < ApplicationRecord

```
  def avg_rating
    reviews.average(:rating).to_f
  end
```

I added this method to my WorkSpace serializer and it returns the data I am looking for.

I then created a method in my WorkSpace model that would calculate the top 5 highest 'rated' work_spaces.

class WorkSpace < ApplicationRecord

```
scope :by_average_for, ->(column) {
    joins(:reviews)
      .group('work_spaces.id')
      .order(Arel.sql("AVG(reviews.#{column}) desc"))
      .having("AVG(reviews.#{column}) > 4", column) if column
  }

  def top_avg_rating
    WorkSpace.by_average_for(:rating).limit(5)
  end
```

The problem I have here is that when I retrieve the data for `top_avg_rating`, it lists the correct work_spaces, but I only get the data that is present in my WorkSpace schema and not the added data I normally get from my WorkSpace serializer. Most importantly, `avg_rating` is not present.

```
  create_table "work_spaces", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "place_id"
    t.float "lat"
    t.float "lng"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "name"
    t.string "address"
    t.string "photo"
    t.integer "cached_votes_total", default: 0
    t.integer "cached_votes_score", default: 0
    t.integer "cached_votes_up", default: 0
    t.integer "cached_votes_down", default: 0
    t.integer "cached_weighted_score", default: 0
    t.integer "cached_weighted_total", default: 0
    t.float "cached_weighted_average", default: 0.0
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_work_spaces_on_user_id"
  end
```

I figured it would be a good idea to store/cache the data I am getting from my WorkSpace model into a new column. So I added a column to my WorkSpace model.

```
t.float "avgrating"
```

I then attempted to store the data for my `avg_rating` into that column.

class WorkSpace < ApplicationRecord

```
  def update_rating
    reviews.average(:rating).to_f

    update(avgrating: reviews.average(:rating).to_f)
  end
```

This actually works, but I have to add this method to my serializer in order to update the column. Is there another way to make sure this method is called? I looked into `after_save` options and caching, but I couldn't put anything together that made sense.

I feel like there has to be a better way to achieve this and I have a strong feeling that I am probably doing this all wrong.

I need to create this same logic for a few more fields from my reviews table, so I'm hoping to settle on a good way to do this before I move forward.

Comment: It sounds like what you want is a [SQL view](https://www.netguru.com/codestories/database-views-and-how-to-use-them-in-a-ror-based-app).

Comment: Thanks @max. Your help always leads to me learn something completely new. I don't have much experience with views, but after reading through that link, this definitely seems like it would solve my issue. I'll give it a shot and see what I can come up with.

Comment: I haven't really done that much with views either but its probably the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

Add `select` to `by_average_for`

```
scope :by_average_for, ->(column) {
  avg_rating = "AVG(reviews.#{column})"

  joins(:reviews)
    .select("work_spaces.*, #{avg_rating} AS avg_rating")
    .group('work_spaces.id')
    .order(Arel.sql("#{avg_rating} desc"))
    .having("#{avg_rating} > 4", column) if column
}
```

then you can access `avg_rating`

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I tried this, but it didn't achieve what I was looking for. I need to access this data from a lot of different places across my app. This particular method was originally only available from the work_space serializer, but I couldn't get the serialized data from the work_space into other related models. I can if I store the data in a column in my work_space table. It's working for me, but I figured there might be a better way. I also use this scope for a few more averages.